# Is there a way to live refresh Maven dependency without build?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I have two Maven projects with project "B" got project "A" as dependency. Every time I change something in "A" I have to rebuild it and then refresh dependencies in "B". Unfortunately, the build takes a few minutes, so for a small change very annoying.

Is there a way to live refresh it without every time a new complete build? In Eclipse I have both projects in one workspace, so every change in "A" was refreshed in "B". Unfortunately, I don't remember if I had to set it up or if it was like that from the beginning.

Comment: I think you mixed your As and Bs. Can you please check? Either in the first sentence A and B need to be swapped or in the second.

Comment: Yeah, mixed them. Fixed.